# Is there a way to show single component in new tab using react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am new to React Router.This is my App component. *StudentDetail* component contains the Link to go to Attendance page. What this does is that It renders *Attendance* Component but keep showing the content of *StudentDetail* in a new tab. What I want: To render only *Attendance* component in the new tab? Is there a way to do this? Thanks in Advance.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Attendance from "./Components/Attendance/Attendance";
import StudentDetail from "./Components/StudentDetail/StudentDetail";

export const StudentContext = createContext();

const StudentData = {
  name: "Faisal Rehman",
  rollNo: "BCSF17M019",
  courses: [
    { courseName: "Computer Architecture", courseAttendance: "" },
    {
      courseName: "Enterprise Application Development",
      courseAttendance: "",
    },
    { courseName: "Computer Vision", courseAttendance: "" },
    { courseName: "Mobile Computing", courseAttendance: "" },
  ],
};

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <StudentContext.Provider value={StudentData}>
          <StudentDetail />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/attendance" component={Attendance} />
          </Switch>
        </StudentContext.Provider>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export { App };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your student detail to the switch and then it will only render one component or the other based on the url. If you are on the base url `/` it will show the `StudentDetail` and if you open `/attendance` in another tab, it should only show `Attendance`.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={StudentDetail} />
    <Route exact path="/attendance" component={Attendance} />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

For default component you can add like this

```
<Router>
  <div className="App">
    <StudentContext.Provider value={StudentData}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/attendance" component={Attendance} />
        <Route path="/">
          <StudentDetail />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </StudentContext.Provider>
  </div>
</Router>
```